# How To split a big image into smaller A4 size pieces using DrawImage method of Graphics class

Tags: c#, graphics

DrawImage method of Graphics class is not creating high quality images. In this method I am splitting a master image into multiple image but the code generating first image in very low quality. But it is generating full black images for remaining height.

```
     public static Bitmap[] Split(byte[] ByteImage)
            {
    // MasterImage:  there is no problem in master image. it is saving it in good quality.
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ByteImage);

                System.Drawing.Image MasterImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

                MasterImage.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../../../App_Shared/Reports/Temp/MasterImage.Bmp"), ImageFormat.Bmp);


    //Split master image into multiple image according to height / 1000
                Int32 ImageHeight = 1000, ImageWidth = MasterImage.Width, MasterImageHeight = MasterImage.Height;
                int PageCount = 0;
                Int32 TotalPages = MasterImage.Height / 1000;
                Bitmap[] imgs = new Bitmap[TotalPages];

                for (int y = 0; y + 1000 < MasterImageHeight; y += 1000, PageCount++)
                {
                    imgs[PageCount] = new Bitmap(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

                    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(imgs[PageCount]))
                    {
                        gr.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                        gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
//First image now working with this code line
 gr.DrawImage(MasterImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, y, ImageWidth, ImageHeight),new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, ImageWidth, ImageHeight), GraphicsUnit.Pixel); //new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new Point(0, y), new Size(ImageWidth, ImageHeight)));
                        //gr.DrawImage(MasterImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, y, ImageWidth, ImageHeight)); //new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new Point(0, y), new Size(ImageWidth, ImageHeight)));

                        string FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../../../App_Shared/Reports/Temp/Image" + PageCount.ToString() + ".bmp");
                        imgs[PageCount].Save(FilePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    //Here it is saving images. I got first image with very poor quality but remaining in total balck color.
                        gr.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                return imgs;
            }
```

[image: My First Image]
[image: and all the other image are black]

Comment: Can you add before and after images to your question showing what is happening?

Comment: Links are dead. Edit..NM its my firewall...

Comment: You reversed the Rectangles in the DrawImage() call.  First one should be (0, 0, ...), second one should be (0, y, ...).  So what you have only works for y = 0.  No hint at all about quality, the source content uses very small fonts with only simple anti-aliasing.  That only ever looks good if you don't look too close.  Like you would on the original image, it is far too large to fit your monitor so it gets zoomed out.

Answer (score 2):

As @HansPassant mentioned the source and target rectangle are reversed.

You could also change the structure of your splitting a bit so it could work a bit more flexible, and it might have a better readability at a later time.

```
class Program
{
    static IList<Bitmap> SplitImage(Bitmap sourceBitmap, int splitHeight)
    {
        Size dimension = sourceBitmap.Size;
        Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, dimension.Width, splitHeight);
        Rectangle targetRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, dimension.Width, splitHeight);

        IList<Bitmap> results = new List<Bitmap>();

        while (sourceRectangle.Top < dimension.Height)
        {
            Bitmap pageBitmap = new Bitmap(targetRectangle.Size.Width, sourceRectangle.Bottom < dimension.Height ?
                targetRectangle.Size.Height
                :
                dimension.Height - sourceRectangle.Top, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pageBitmap))
            {
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
                g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, targetRectangle, sourceRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            sourceRectangle.Y += sourceRectangle.Height;
            results.Add(pageBitmap);
        }

        return results;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceFilename = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\testimage.jpg";
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(sourceFilename);

        var images = SplitImage(sourceBitmap, 79);
        int len = images.Count;
        for (int x = len; --x >= 0; )
        {
            var bmp = images[x];
            string filename = "Images-" + x + ".bmp";
            bmp.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\" + filename, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            images.RemoveAt(x);
            bmp.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Saved " + filename);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done with the resizing");
    }
}
```

This would also dynamically size the last image in case the page is less than your specified bitmap height at the end :)

Comment: Thanks for solution and extra functionality "dynamically size the last image"